# Redirecting to another page and passing in values

Tags: angularjs, node.js, strongloop

I want to redirect to another page while passing in the id parameter, how do I do that? This is my code which I tried after searching for examples. I already created a visit form where I can pass in all the visit information. After that I'll displaying the visit information and have a button to click to redirect me to a form where I create trips. I want to get the id of the visit to create trips according to the visit that they clicked on. I have added photos of the ui to make it more understandable.

[image: Create Trip Page] [image: Create Visit Page] [image: View Visit Page]

Codes I added in my html page

```
<button ng-click="redirect()">Start Planning trips!</button>
```

Codes in my controller

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
$location.path('#/create-trip').search('id=' + $scope.visit.id); }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
     $location.path('#/create-trip').search('id',$scope.visit.id);
}
```

OR

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
    var param = {
        id: $scope.visit.id
    }
    $location.url("/store/items").search(param);
}
```